# Ternary operator in LINQ query is not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I'm trying to filter a list of objects based on some conditions. I've seen a few posts that use ternary operators in their LINQ query to accomplish this.

At the bottom of this code snippet  is my LINQ query. I expected it to test each `where`, instead it only seems to try the first `where` and leave the rest. The `List` does not contain the data I expect it to. What am I doing wrong?

```
    private ObservableCollection<LogEvent> m_LogEvents = ApplicationData.MainLogEntries.LogEvents;
    public ObservableCollection<LogEvent> LogEvents
    {
        get { return m_LogEvents; }
        set { m_LogEvents = value; RaisePropertyChanged("LogEvents"); }
    }

    private bool m_ViewDebugLogs = false;
    public bool ViewDebugLogs
    {
        get { return m_ViewDebugLogs; }
        set { m_ViewDebugLogs = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ViewDebugLogs"); FilterList(); }
    }

    private bool m_ViewErrorLogs = true;
    public bool ViewErrorLogs
    {
        get { return m_ViewErrorLogs; }
        set { m_ViewErrorLogs = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ViewErrorLogs"); FilterList(); }
    }

    private bool m_ViewInfoLogs = true;
    public bool ViewInfoLogs
    {
        get { return m_ViewInfoLogs; }
        set { m_ViewInfoLogs = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ViewInfoLogs"); FilterList(); }
    }

    private void FilterList()
    {
        List<LogEvent> selectedEvents = (from x in LogEvents
                                         where (ViewDebugLogs) ? x.Level == "Debug" : false
                                         where (ViewErrorLogs) ? x.Level == "Error" : false
                                         where (ViewInfoLogs) ? x.Level == "Info" : false
                                         select x).ToList();

    }
```

Edit: The goal of this is if the appropriate bool `ViewDebugLogs`, `ViewErrorLogs`, or `ViewInfoLogs`, or any combination of the three are enabled the logs are filtered by the appropriate types.

I've tried the following from the answers with no success:

This gets only `Debug Logs`:

```
            List<LogEvent> selectedEvents = (from x in LogEvents
                                         where (ViewDebugLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Debug" : false
                                         || (ViewErrorLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Error" : false
                                         || (ViewInfoLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Info" : false
                                         select x).ToList();
```

This gets only `Debug Logs`:

```
            List<LogEvent> selectedEvents = (from x in LogEvents
                                         where (ViewDebugLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Debug" : true
                                         || (ViewErrorLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Error" : true
                                         || (ViewInfoLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Info" : true
                                         select x).ToList();
```

This gets nothing:

```
            List<LogEvent> selectedEvents = (from x in LogEvents
                                         where (ViewDebugLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Debug" : true
                                         where (ViewErrorLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Error" : true
                                         where (ViewInfoLogs == true) ? x.Level == "Info" : true
                                         select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
 List<LogEvent> selectedEvents = (from x in LogEvents
                           where (ViewDebugLogs && x.Level == "Debug") 
                              || (ViewErrorLogs && x.Level == "Error")
                              || (ViewInfoLogs  && x.Level == "Info") 
                           select x).ToList();
```

That is much clearer (in my opinion). Note the `( )` around the expression parts: I want to make sure of the order in which the ANDs and ORs are evaluated.

Comment: The brackets are what did it, combined with using `||` instead of multiple `where`s. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Multiple `where` conditions are concatenated as if you used `AND`. If you're trying to do `OR` you should use `||` instead.

```
List<LogEvent> selectedEvents = (from x in LogEvents
                                 where (ViewDebugLogs) ? x.Level == "Debug" : false
                                 || (ViewErrorLogs) ? x.Level == "Error" : false
                                 || (ViewInfoLogs) ? x.Level == "Info" : false
                                 select x).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's good to know on multiple `where`s. I tried that earlier, and the query returns only debug logs. If I just query `where (ViewDebugLogs) ? x.Level == "Info" : false` without the two other wheres (or any one of the three listed there) it returns the expected data. Just tried it again in case I messed it up earlier, same results.

Comment: Try and add extra brackets (as in `where ((ViewDebugLogs) ? x.Level == "Debug" : false)`

Comment: The brackets did it! I definitely did not think those where necessary for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Where` clause can be `where (ViewDebugLogs) ? x.Level == "Debug" : ((ViewErrorLogs) ? x.Level == "Error" : ((ViewInfoLogs) ? x.Level == "Info" : false))`